# CodeIgniter: How is $this available from the root of a view?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I understand that $this refers to the current object.

However, normally, referring to $this in the root of a file (not within an object) will cause an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in - on line 2
```

..but in a view, I have this code:

```
<?php
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view($view);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

How is PHP finding the global / singleton CI instance from the $this reference?

Comment: `$this->load->view(file)` means  `include file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your view is loaded into a call to `eval` or via `include` in the `_ci_load` method of the `Loader` class.  The method also gets the `CI` instance.

see `./system/core/Loader.php`

Getting the instance on line 920

```
$_ci_CI =& get_instance();
```

Loading the view into `eval` or by `include` on line 969

```
// If the PHP installation does not support short tags we'll
// do a little string replacement, changing the short tags
// to standard PHP echo statements.
if ( ! is_php('5.4') && ! ini_get('short_open_tag') && config_item('rewrite_short_tags') === TRUE)
{
    echo eval('?>'.preg_replace('/;*\s*\?>/', '; ?>', str_replace('<?=', '<?php echo ', file_get_contents($_ci_path))));
}
else
{
    include($_ci_path); // include() vs include_once() allows for multiple views with the same name
}
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, but this one is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

When `$this->load->view()` is called in a controller the view file is brought into the controller class with PHP's `include` command. So the view's code becomes part of the controller's class - becomes part of `$this`'s scope.

Comment: I wish I could accept this one as well, as it's accurate.